# How do I determine if a particular assembly is available in Client Profile?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, .net-client-profile

Given a particular reference assembly, what is the best way of determining whether it is available in a client profile or not?

Comment: Good questions, also struggled over that. However, besides try-and-error I can not suggest a method.